# how to match a motif where one character could be anything

Tags: python

If I have a DNA region and they ask me to find  TAnAnT where n could be any letter that I want. How do I do that using python?

And if n is limited to be A/C?

ex:

DNA = ("TTATCG", "TACACT", "GGGCA")
count = 0
if (TAnAnT) in DNA:
count += count +1
print(count)

Comment: elaborate your question, show what you have done

Comment: Use ``r"T(A.)\1T"`` or ``r"T(A[AC])\1T"`` if the first ``n`` should be the same as the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex for this purpose, use `r1` for first case and `r2` for second case.

```python
import re

r1 = re.compile("TA.A.T")
r2 = re.compile("TA[AC]A[AC]T")
print(r1.findall("TAxA T"))
print(r2.findall("TACAAT"))
```